# Select Option (2 dependent) based on array jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
[{
    "subclass": "Class 1",
    "SubClass": [{
        "subclass": "Class 1",
        "subid": "1",
        "price": "1.6625"
    }, {
        "subclass": "Class 1",
        "subid": "2",
        "price": "1.575"
    }]
}, {
    "subclass": "Class 2",
    "SubClass": [{
        "subclass": "Class 2",
        "subid": "1",
        "price": "3.0625"
    }, {
        "subclass": "Class 2",
        "subid": "2",
        "price": "2.8"
    }, {
        "subclass": "Class 2",
        "subid": "3",
        "price": "2.5375"
    }, {
        "subclass": "Class 2",
        "subid": "4",
        "price": "2.275"
    }]
}]


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var SubClass = data[i].SubClass;
    for (var j = 0; j < SubClass.length; j++) {

        $(selectid).append('<option id=' + SubClass[j].subid + ' value="' + SubClass[j].subid + '">' + SubClass[j].subid + '</option>');

    }
    $(selectclass).append('<option id=' + data[i].subid + ' value="' + data[i].subclass + '">' + data[i].subclass + '</option>');
}
```

I have this array above and i want to put the `subclass` value of the array into one select and the `subid` in the next select. My problem is i want to show only the `subid` that is available for each `subclass` currently in my code it is showing all subid

`UPDATE`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/boz3cops/)

Here is a fiddle what i expect here is for `Class 1` the id is only `1 and 2` for `Class 2` the id is `1 , 2 , 3 , and 4`

Comment: Can you put together a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a change event handler

```
var selectclass = $('#selectclass');
selectclass.empty();
var selectid = $('#selectid');
selectid.empty();

$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    $('<option id=' + item.subid + ' value="' + item.subclass + '">' + item.subclass + '</option>').appendTo(selectclass).data('item', item);
});

selectclass.on('change.selectid', function () {
    var item = $(this).find('option:selected').data('item');
    selectid.empty();
    $.each(item.SubClass, function (i, sub) {
        $('<option id=' + sub.subid + ' value="' + sub.subid + '">' + sub.subid + '</option>').appendTo(selectid);
    });
}).trigger('change.selectid');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8k5mbLsz/)

Comment: $selectclass is not defined

Comment: is there no way to do this without onchange i mean a way in which to show the id depending on the class?

Comment: @HogRider sorry... what do you mean by `show the id depending on the class`

Comment: where did you put the class `selectid` in this lines  `change.selectid` and `selectclass.on('change.selectid', function () {` i cant find them because in html the class attr is empty

Comment: @HogRider that is called a namespace in the context of events - http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names

Comment: Last question for this question sir. How do i get the value of the select option on load. i tried all possible tutorial but i always get undefined but when the change happened the value is ok i want to get the value of select even before the onchange happened.

Comment: @HogRider sorry... what do you mean... try to give the steps to recreate the issue

Comment: for example in your fiddle if we put the line `alert($('selectclass').val())` right after `$.each(data, function (i, item) {` to show the value of `Class 1` which is the default value of that select the alert is undefined not the value of `Class 1`

Comment: @HogRider http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8k5mbLsz/4/ - `selectclass` is a jQuery variable so there is no need to enclose it in `''` else use `alert($('#selectclass').val())`